# Determine device architecture (ARM/ARM64/x86) with 'adb getprop'

Tags: adb, arm-processors

Using `adb getprop`, I've found a few values that I think are pertinent, but I don't have any idea what an ARM64 device's value would like, much less an x86 one.

For my ARM device, the values are:

```
ro.product.cpu.abi       armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2      armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32 armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64
```

I though `armabi-v8a` would mean ARM64, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARMv8-A_cores) says

> most chips support 32-bit AArch32 for legacy applications

So, I'm wondering if an ARMv8 chip could possibly be loaded with 32-bit Android which would further complicate things

Is there any way I can determine my device architecture with `adb`?

Comment: "I'm wondering if an armv8 chip could possibly be loaded with 32bit android" - definitely, Samsung/Moto did this for a bunch of past 64bit SoC devices.

Comment: To answer your curiosity, this is what it would look like on a 64bit device: `[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [arm64-v8a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: [arm64-v8a]` I cannot check with an x86 device as I have none. But I'd say the picture is comparable: just check whether `abilist64` has a value. If so, it's a 64bit device, otherwise it's running in 32bit mode.

Answer (score 4):

I did some poking around in some custom ROMs for x86 devices, and along with the info provided by @Izzy I think I've figured it out.

Example ARM64 device

```
ro.product.cpu.abilist32  armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64  arm64-v8a
```

Example ARM device

```
ro.product.cpu.abilist32  armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64
```

Example x86 device

```
ro.product.cpu.abilist32  x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64
```

So, to figure out what kind of device you have:

`ro.product.cpu.abilist64` not empty = `ARM64`

`ro.product.cpu.abilist32` contains `x86` = `x86`

If none of these conditions match, you have an `ARM` device